# Promise resolved but returns part of data - rest 'undefined'

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm having an issue with a Promise that gets returned from MongoDB's mLab. Part of the data is passed correctly, rest is undefined. I'm not sure what is going on here.

This is JSON object from a collection in mLab that I connect to.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "591424da932aad14186a7213"
    },
    "name": "Archos Elements 50 Oxygen",
    "weight_oz": 4.59,
    "battery_capacity_mAh": 2300,
    "platform": "Android",
    "date": {
        "$date": "2017-05-11T08:46:18.684Z"
    },
    "dimensions": {
        "width_mm": 70.5,
        "height_mm": 143,
        "depth_mm": 9.9
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

This is how I retrieve the data (body-parser is used to capture 'name' of the phone that user inputs via HTML form)

```
router.post('/page_2', function(req, res){
phone = req.body.phone
mobile_and_tablet_model.find({name:phone}).exec(function(err, result) {
        if (err) 
            throw err;
    }).then(function(MongoDBdata){
        console.log(MongoDBdata[0]) // logs out entire JSON object correctly
        console.log(MongoDBdata[0]._id) // 5002
        console.log(MongoDBdata[0].name) // Archos Elements 50 Oxygen
        console.log(MongoDBdata[0].weight_oz) // undefined
        console.log(MongoDBdata[0].battery_capacity_mAh) // undefined
        console.log(MongoDBdata[0].platform) // Android
        console.log(MongoDBdata[0].date) // 2017-05-11T08:06:27.894Z
        console.log(MongoDBdata[0].dimensions) // undefined
        res.render('page_2.hbs', {
            title: 'some title', 
            phone: phone,
            battery_capacity: MongoDBdata[0].battery_capacity_mAh, // undefined
            platform: MongoDBdata[0].platform // Android
        })
    })
})
```

Can someone help me understand this behavior & help me fix it ?

I don't understand why am I getting 'undefined' for some nested values on the JSON object. I'm far from being an expert on Promises, but if I understand correctly then promise has been resolved, so the sync/async behavior should not play a role here ? (especially since console.log(MongoDBdata[0]) logged out the JSON content in full).

Much appreciated!

Comment: why are you using both a callback in `exec()` and a promise when you can just use one of them ? `exec()` return a promise so you can handle errors with `.catch(function(error){ //do whaterver you want with this error  });`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @mJehanno. I adjusted code accordingly. Makes perfect sense. Unfortunately, issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it.

It was problem with the schema which I have not adjusted (one schema was used for uploading data to MongoDB, another one for retrieving - I have changed one for uploading, but not the other one for downloading)

That is the reason why some data could return 'undefined' (even though the JSON retrieved from collection has logged out 100% correct). When I tried to access nested values on the object, I was effectively using incorrect mongoose model.

Schema from below works (all values that were returning 'undefined' now return correct values). Hopefully someone could benefit from my mistake.